# In the mobile chat, when trying to delete my last message, and it is too old, the alert is too huge

Tags: bug, chat, design

[image]

Using SGS5, Chrome.

Maybe replace it with standard browser alert?

Comment: [this alert](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O1FYM.png) is also too large.